# subprocess.call logger info and error for stdout and stderr

Tags: python

I have a logger. I am calling an external process. I capture stdout and stderr seperatly from that process so that I can log them.

***I have this error:***

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "importData.py", line 198,
>   in 
>       importData(ftpServerName,ftpU,ftpP,directory,filematch,source,destination)
>   File "importData.py", line 99, in importData
>       p = subprocess.Popen(['mongoimport --db AutoPrivilege -c cars stockvo.json --jsonArray --upsert --drop'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
>   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
>   line 710, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

***my script:***

```
...
        #import json file to MongoDB
        logger.info(' Import json file to MongoDB')
        #subprocess.call('mongoimport --db AutoPrivilege -c cars stockvo.json --jsonArray --upsert --drop',shell=True)
        p = subprocess.Popen(["mongoimport --db AutoPrivilege -c cars stockvo.json --jsonArray --upsert --drop"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

        if stdout:
            logger.info(stdout)
        if stderr:
            logger.error(stderr)
...
```

Is there a way to resolved that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` constructor accepts list of args, not string:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['mongoimport', '--db', 'AutoPrivilege', '-c',
                      'cars', 'stockvo.json', '--jsonArray', '--upsert',
                      '--drop'])...
```